# Getting the error AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'GoTo'" when executing a python script in selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am using selenium with python for automation. Here are the two .py files I have created:

**Browser.py:**

```
from selenium import webdriver

class Browser:

    def GoTo(self, url):
        browser.get(url)

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

**Login.py:**

```
import unittest
from Browser import *

class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def test_Can_Login(self):
        browser.GoTo("http://www.google.co.in")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

When I run Login.py, Firefox opens but does nothing. It throws an error saying:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/Pinku/Tests/src/Login.py", line 10, in test_Can_Login
    browser.GoTo("http://www.google.co.in")
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'GoTo'"
```

Am I overlooking something here. Posting this after trying hard to find the mistake.Please help!

Comment: are you really that desperate that you can't live without a new custom http verb called `goto`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your `browser` is an instance of `Firefox`, not the class you have defined.

```
class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = Browser()
    def test_Can_Login(self):
        self.browser.GoTo("http://www.google.co.in")
```

However, if you want to wrap the functionality of `Firefox`, you should consider subclassing it instead of using global variables.

```
class Browser(webdriver.Firefox):
    def GoTo(self, url):
        self.get(url)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @ARodas. It worked! First stint with stack overflow and I was not disappointed!